# How to apply datatables using Vuejs with Laravel

Tags: vue.js, search, datatables, pagination

I am populating table but now I want to apply pagination, searching, filter criteria. I am new to Vue, how I can apply into my code?

Below is my Vue file:

```
<template>

    <div>
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Logs</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Logs</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-header -->

        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="content">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-header -->
                            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="width: 1000px;">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>User Id</th>
                                        <th>Message Title</th>
                                        <th>Process Type</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Data Load</th>
                                        <th>Message Code</th>
                                        <th>Log Type</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr v-for="socket in sockets">
                                        <td>{{socket.id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{socket.user_id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{socket.message_title}}</td>
                                        <td>{{socket.process_type}}</td>
                                        <td>{{socket.description}}</td>
                                        <td>{{socket.data_load}}</td>
                                        <td>{{socket.msg_code}}</td>
                                        <td>{{socket.log_type}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.content -->

    </div>

</template>
```

This is my script where I am getting all the data from my database.

```
    <script>
    
        export default {
    
            data() {
    
                return {
                    sockets: [],
                    form: new Form({
                        'user_id': '',
                        'message_title': '',
                        'process_type': '',
                        'description': '',
                        'data_load': '',
                        'msg_code': '',
                        'log_type': '',
                    })
                }
    
            },
    
    
            created() {
                axios.get('/message')
                    .then(({data}) => this.sockets = data);
            },
    
            methods: {
                onSubmit(){
                    //this.form.password_confirmation = this.form.password; // Temp for this form only.
                    this.form
                        .post('/message')
                        .then(socket => this.sockets.push(socket));
                }
            }
        }
    
    </script>
```

I also add the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following approach for your case: First, you have a data variable `sockets` where you collect all records data from your API. For the pagination I would create another variable which determines the page at which the user is (`pageIndex`) and another variable which describes how many items exist on each page (`itemsOnPage`). Then using these variable you can create a `computed` property to filter the data only for that page and then use this computed property in your template for the table instead of directly using `sockets`. Example:

```
<template>
    <tr v-for="socket in paginatedSockets">
      <td>{{ socket.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ socket.user_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ socket.message_title }}</td>
      <td>{{ socket.process_type }}</td>
      <td>{{ socket.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ socket.data_load }}</td>
      <td>{{ socket.msg_code }}</td>
      <td>{{ socket.log_type }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    paginatedSockets() {
      return this.sockets.filter((socket, index) => {
        // Filter the array fo get only the items you want from this.sockets, something like that (this is not complete):
        return index < this.itemsOnPage;
      });
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sockets: [],
      pageIndex: 0,
      itemsOnPage: 10,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

About the filtering you can extend this computed property with logic for this. You can have for example an `<input v-model="searchCriteria"/>` which binds to a data variable `searchCriteria` and then use it in `paginatedSockets`. Example:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    paginatedSockets() {
      return this.sockets.filter((socket, index) => {
        // Filter the array fo get only the items you want from this.sockets, something like that (this is not complete):
        return socket === this.searchCriteria && index < this.itemsOnPage;
      });
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sockets: [],
      pageIndex: 0,
      itemsOnPage: 10,
      searchCriteria: ''
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I hope this helps.